# java sql connectivity

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc, odbc

I have created a user dsn named "harshi"
To insert rows in a table getting data from Java code I want to insert in SQL table.
The connection statement is:

```
String url = "jdbc:odbc:Harshi"; 
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"",""); 
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
```

Still I am getting output as:

> Got an exception!
>   [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver][Shared Memory]SQL Server does
>   not exist or access denied.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

To troubleshoot this error, try one of these:

- does the DSN contain good credentials?
- If using SQL Server Authentication, try logging in using those exact credentials via SQL Server Management Studio
- If using Windows Authentication, does the account making the request have permissions to the SQL Server?
- Are there any firewalls in between the application machine and the database machine?
- Has the IP address of the destination machine changed since the DSN was created?
- Try deleting & recreating the DSN.